# Spring boot application with swagger 2 gets null on run()

Tags: java, spring-boot, config, swagger-2.0

I have a simple Spring Boot application for an API what I wanted to document with Swagger. I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the main class.

**My Main Class:**

```java
    package com.local.parking.test;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*", methods = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE }, allowCredentials = "true")
    //@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.local.parking.test.config"})
    public class ParkingApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Parking");
            SpringApplication.run(ParkingApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

**The error was thrown here:**

```
SpringApplication.run(ParkingApplication.class, args);`
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
at com.local.parking.test.ParkingApplication.main(ParkingApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
```

**My Swagger config class:**

```java
    package com.local.parking.test.config;
    
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
    import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
    import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
    import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
    //                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.controller")) // Set your base package here
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.local.parking.test.parking"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build()
                    .apiInfo(apiInfo());
        }
    
        private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
            return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                    .title("Parking Management API")
                    .description("API for managing parking spaces and bookings")
                    .version("1.0")
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

**The POM file:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.local</groupId>
        <artifactId>parkingtest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>parking</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Swagger 2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Connection pooling dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- for flyway -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
    
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>    
    </project>
```

What causes the null pointer or how can I fix it?

Comment: when I remove annotation `@EnableSwagger2` there is no error message